# Simple, graphical Public / Private Key and RSA Keys Tool for Mac or Windows?

Tags: encryption, ssh

I'm looking for a simple GUI tool for Mac or Windows (ideally both) which makes working with keypairs easy. For example:

Generate a public key, describe a key file, determine if a public and private key are a match, etc

- Not complex key management, but the basics.

For example, over time I have various public keys and private keys for different SSH servers, projects or customers. Some are different formats. I don't mind command line tools but it would be nice to have an easy way to do these things without any wizardry.

The closest I found was PuttyGen but that's only a GUI for Windows, and still pretty cryptic.

Especially in this age where everyone codes and uses AWS, there's got to be a simple tool out there.

Answer (score 2):

I looked for something similar long ago, and have since become a slave to the command line. However, I recently received a license for [SSH Config Editor Pro for Mac](https://www.hejki.org/ssheditor/) in a software bundle, and it looks promising. It looks like there's a non-"pro" edition you could also try, but I can't speak for it, myself.